# Cannot delete regs on a SQL table in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL Server table linked in an Access app. If I try to delete records with a delete query there is no problem. But if I try to delete records directly in table or using a select query in datasheet mode Access doesn't allow me to delete the records and throws the following warning:

> "The microsoft access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time."

The same happens when I try to update data. There is no other user modifying the data.

The problem is that we still have a lot of legacy forms that uses datasheet mode to alter o delete records instead of using queryes and, for now, changing all these forms is unthinkable.

¿Has anyone any idea of what could be happening?

Thanks!

**FINAL EDIT:**
The problem was a bit field that was set to nullable that, thanks to Kostas K. I discovered is not convertable to Access.

So, instead of this:

`[FIELD] [bit] NULL`

We need tis:

`[FIELD] [bit] NOT NULL`

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [FIELD] GO`

**UPDATE:** This locking only happens with new records added from Access, but not with the original records of the SQL table.

This is the script to create the table:

`

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Chapas].[INFO_CHAPAS](
[ID_INFO_CHAPA] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[COD_EQUIPO] [int] NULL,
[EQUIPO] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[NUMERO_SERIE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[FASES] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[VOLTAJE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[FRECUENCIA] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[POTENCIA] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[AÑO] [int] NULL,
[IMPRESO] [bit] NULL,
[SELECTOR_REGISTRO] [bit] NULL,
[USUARIO] [int] NULL,
[FECHA_IMPRESION] datetime NULL

CONSTRAINT [INFO_CHAPAS_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[ID_INFO_CHAPA] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY 
= OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Chapas].[INFO_CHAPAS] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IMPRESO]
GO
```

`

Comment: Probably an issue with specific data types. Please add the full CREATE TABLE statement to your question, and also which ODBC driver you use.

Comment: Does "regs" mean "records"?

Comment: Yes, regs mean records. I'll edit the question with the full word.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you closing the recordset after you add the new record? Or are you using a stored procedure to insert the record? If it's a linked form - perhaps the new record is still in edit mode? Without your code we can only guess

Comment: Check data types on SQL server table, for example nullable BIT etc - Access cannot handle those.

Comment: @dbmitch In fact there is no code. I'm trying the very basic, that is operating directly on the bare table and the problem persists, so I discard problems with the form or with the query. I also checked datatypes and are simply varchar, int and bit with an identity(1,1) so nothing strange or not convertable to Access (afaik). 

I updated This is the script to create the table if that helps.

Comment: @KostasK. That's it! The nullable bit... The problem was solved creating the bit field not nullable and with a default value of 0.

Thank all of you for your time and ideas.